# Assign Local Group Membership & Permissions for CRM Service Accounts

Tags: sql-server, powershell, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

The PowerShell does this:

- Disables UAC on the CRM Servers (You can turn it back on after installation)
- Turns Off the Firewall on CRM Servers (You can turn it back on after installation and configure Firewall Rules)
  Adds CRM Application Account to IIS_IUSRS and Performance Log Users groups in Front-end servers
- Adds CRM Deployment Account to IIS_IUSRS and Local Administrators groups in Deployment Servers
- Adds CRM Async Service Account to Performance Log Users group in Back-end servers
- Gives Logon as a Service permission to corresponding Service Accounts
- Adds CRM Deployment Account to Local Administrators group in SQL Server
- Adds CRM Deployment Account to SQL Server as sysadmin

  ```
  function Assign-Permissions
          {
            $fullRolesServers = "WDPWD99A0310"
            foreach($server in $fullRolesServers)
            {
              $session0 = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential Administrator;
              $output = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock{
                function Disable-Uac()
                {
                  if((Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system -Name EnableLUA -ea 0).EnableLUA -eq 0)
                  {
                    Write-Host "UAC is disabled" -f darkcyan;
                  }
                  else              
                  {
                    Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system -Name EnableLUA -Value 0
                    Write-Host "UAC has been disabled" -f darkGreen;
                  }
                }                
                Write-Host "Server:$env:computerName - Disabling UAC" -f darkcyan;
                Disable-Uac;
                Write-Host "Server:$env:computerName - Turning Off Firewall"  -f darkcyan;
                netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off;
              };
              Remove-PSSession -Session $session0;

              $iisGroup = "WinNT://"+$server+"/IIS_IUSRS,group"
              $perfoGroup = "WinNT://"+$server+"/Performance Log Users,group"
              $adminGroup = "WinNT://"+$server+"/Administrators,group"

              Write-Host "Server:$server - Adding CRM Application Account to IIS_IUSRS and Performance Log Users groups" -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
              if(!(([ADSI]$iisGroup).IsMember(([ADSI]"WinNT://TESTBIZTALK/CRMAppSvc").path)))
                   {([ADSI]$iisGroup).psbase.Invoke("Add",([ADSI]"WinNT://TESTBIZTALK/CRMAppSvc").path);}

              if(!(([ADSI]$perfoGroup).IsMember(([ADSI]"WinNT://TESTBIZTALK/CRMAppSvc").path)))
                   {([ADSI]$perfoGroup).psbase.Invoke("Add",([ADSI]"WinNT://TESTBIZTALK/CRMAppSvc").path);}

              Write-Host "Server:$server - Adding CRM Deployment Account to IIS_IUSRS and Local Administrators groups" -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
              if(!(([ADSI]$iisGroup).IsMember(([ADSI]"WinNT://TESTBIZTALK/CRMAppSvc").path)))
                   {([ADSI]$iisGroup).psbase.Invoke("Add",([ADSI]"WinNT://TESTBIZTALK/CRMAppSvc").path);}
              if(!(([ADSI]$adminGroup).IsMember(([ADSI]"WinNT://TESTBIZTALK/CRMAppSvc").path)))
                   {([ADSI]$adminGroup).psbase.Invoke("Add",([ADSI]"WinNT://TESTBIZTALK/CRMAppSvc").path);}

              Write-Host "Server:$server - Adding CRM Async Service Account to Performance Log Users group" -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
              if(!(([ADSI]$perfoGroup).IsMember(([ADSI]"WinNT://TESTBIZTALK/CRMAsyncSvc").path)))
                   {([ADSI]$perfoGroup).psbase.Invoke("Add",([ADSI]"WinNT://TESTBIZTALK/CRMAsyncSvc").path);}

              $output=Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock{
              function AddLogonAsAService($accountToAdd)
              {
                if( [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($accountToAdd) ) 
                {
                  Write-Host "no account specified" -f red;
                  exit;
                }
                $sidstr = $null
                try
                {
                  $ntprincipal = new-object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount "$accountToAdd"
                  $sid = $ntprincipal.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
                  $sidstr = $sid.Value.ToString()
                }
                catch 
                {
                  $sidstr = $null
                }
                Write-Host "Server:$env:computerName - Adding ""Logon as a Service"" right to Account: $accountToAdd" -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
                if( [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($sidstr) )
                {
                   Write-Host "Account not found!" -ForegroundColor Red
                   exit -1
                }
                #Write-Host "Account SID: $($sidstr)" -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
                $tmp = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
                #Write-Host "Export current Local Security Policy" -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
                secedit.exe /export /cfg "$($tmp)" 

                $c = Get-Content -Path $tmp 
                $currentSetting = ""

                foreach($s in $c)
                {
                  if( $s -like "SeServiceLogonRight*")
                  {
                    $x = $s.split("=",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    $currentSetting = $x[1].Trim()
                  }
                }
                if( $currentSetting -notlike "*$($sidstr)*" )
                {
                  Write-Host "Modify Setting 'Logon as a Service'" -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
                  if( [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($currentSetting) )
                  {
                    $currentSetting = "*$($sidstr)"
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    $currentSetting = "*$($sidstr),$($currentSetting)"
                  }
                  #Write-Host "$currentSetting"
                  $outfile = @"
          [Unicode]
          Unicode=yes
          [Version]
          signature="`$CHICAGO`$"
          Revision=1
          [Privilege Rights]
          SeServiceLogonRight = $($currentSetting)
          "@
                  $tmp2 = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
                  #Write-Host "Import new settings to Local Security Policy" -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
                  $outfile | Set-Content -Path $tmp2 -Encoding Unicode -Force
                  Push-Location (Split-Path $tmp2)

                  try
                  {
                    secedit.exe /configure /db "secedit.sdb" /cfg "$($tmp2)" /areas USER_RIGHTS 
                  }
                  finally
                  { 
                    Pop-Location
                  }
                }
                else
                {
                  Write-Host "NO ACTIONS REQUIRED! Account already in ""Logon as a Service""" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
                }
                Write-Host "Done." -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
              }
              AddLogonAsAService "TESTBIZTALK\CRMAsyncSvc";
              AddLogonAsAService "TESTBIZTALK\CRMSandboxSvc";
              AddLogonAsAService "TESTBIZTALK\CRMAppSvc";
              AddLogonAsAService "TESTBIZTALK\CRMVssSvc";
              AddLogonAsAService "TESTBIZTALK\CRMMonSvc";
            }
          }
          if(!(([ADSI]"WinNT://WDVMA76A0530/Administrators,group").IsMember(([ADSI]"WinNT://TESTBIZTALK/CRMAppSvc").path)))
              {([ADSI]"WinNT://WDVMA76A0530/Administrators,group").psbase.Invoke("Add",([ADSI]"WinNT://TESTBIZTALK/CRMAppSvc").path);}

          $output=Invoke-Command -ComputerName WDVMA76A0530 -ScriptBlock{
            function createLogin()
            {
              try
              {
                $instanceName = "MSSQLSERVER"
                $LoginName = "TESTBIZTALK\CRMAppSvc"
                Import-Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking
                if ($instanceName -eq "MSSQLSERVER")
                {
                  $server = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server -ArgumentList WDVMA76A0530
                }
                else
                {
                  $server = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server -ArgumentList WDVMA76A0530\$instanceName        
                }              
                if ($server.Logins.Contains($LoginName))
                {    
                  Write-Host $LoginName "Already exists..."
                }
                else
                {
                  $SqlLogin = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Login -ArgumentList $server, "$LoginName"
                  $SqlLogin.LoginType = 'WindowsUser'        
                  $SqlLogin.Create()
                  $SqlLogin.AddToRole('sysadmin')
                  Write-Host $LoginName "Login created successfully"  -f darkgreen;
                }
              }
              catch
              {     
                Write-Host "Could not create Login - Error: " $($_.Exception.Message) -f red;
              }
             }
             createLogin;
            }
          }
          Assign-Permissions;
  ```

  [image: Error]

[image: Error1]

open suggestion those are interested in powershell remoting and CRM 2016 installation from local machine.

environment details:
TestDC1 Domain controller
WDPWD99A0310 CRM 
WDVMA76A0530 SQL

Answer (score 0):

I had working PowerShell script for "Assign Local Group Membership & Permissions for CRM Service Accounts" from other "LAB" environment.. the Issue with previous Script was with "PowerShell Remoting" please ensure it is fully setup on your Environment.

### "PowerShell Remoting"

Follow the path: Computer Configuration \ Policies \ Windows Settings \ Security Settings \ Windows Firewall with Advanced Security 
Here, right-click on Inbound Rules and then in New Rule. In the window that appears, enable the Predefinedtype and select Windows Remote Management.

[image: Windows Firewall setup]

Choose whether to allow access to Domain / Private networks and/or Public networks.

[image: predefined Rules]

Finally, leave Allow the connection enabled and click "Finish" to create the new rules in the Windows Firewall.

[image: Allow connection enabled]

```
#PS Function: Assign Local Group Membership & Permissions for CRM Service Accounts 
        function Assign-Permissions
    {
      $fullRolesServers = "BTLab2016".Split(";");
      foreach($server in $fullRolesServers)
      {
        $session0 = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server;
        $output = Invoke-Command -Session $session0 -ScriptBlock{
          function Disable-Uac()
          {
            if((Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system -Name EnableLUA -ea 0).EnableLUA -eq 0)
            {
              Write-Host "UAC is disabled" -f darkcyan;
            }
            else              
            {
              Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system -Name EnableLUA -Value 0
              Write-Host "UAC has been disabled" -f darkGreen;
            }
          }                
          Write-Host "Server:$env:computerName - Disabling UAC" -f darkcyan;
          Disable-Uac;
          Write-Host "Server:$env:computerName - Turning Off Firewall"  -f darkcyan;
          netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off;
        };
        Remove-PSSession -Session $session0;

        $iisGroup = "WinNT://"+$server+"/IIS_IUSRS,group"
        $perfoGroup = "WinNT://"+$server+"/Performance Log Users,group"
        $adminGroup = "WinNT://"+$server+"/Administrators,group"
        
        Write-Host "Server:$server - Adding CRM Application Account to IIS_IUSRS and Performance Log Users groups" -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
        if(!(([ADSI]$iisGroup).IsMember(([ADSI]"WinNT://BIZTALK2016/CrmAppServiceDEV").path)))
             {([ADSI]$iisGroup).psbase.Invoke("Add",([ADSI]"WinNT://BIZTALK2016/CrmAppServiceDEV").path);}
        
        if(!(([ADSI]$perfoGroup).IsMember(([ADSI]"WinNT://BIZTALK2016/CrmAppServiceDEV").path)))
             {([ADSI]$perfoGroup).psbase.Invoke("Add",([ADSI]"WinNT://BIZTALK2016/CrmAppServiceDEV").path);}

        Write-Host "Server:$server - Adding CRM Deployment Account to IIS_IUSRS and Local Administrators groups" -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
        if(!(([ADSI]$iisGroup).IsMember(([ADSI]"WinNT://BIZTALK2016/CrmAppServiceDEV").path)))
             {([ADSI]$iisGroup).psbase.Invoke("Add",([ADSI]"WinNT://BIZTALK2016/CrmAppServiceDEV").path);}
        if(!(([ADSI]$adminGroup).IsMember(([ADSI]"WinNT://BIZTALK2016/CrmAppServiceDEV").path)))
             {([ADSI]$adminGroup).psbase.Invoke("Add",([ADSI]"WinNT://BIZTALK2016/CrmAppServiceDEV").path);}

        Write-Host "Server:$server - Adding CRM Async Service Account to Performance Log Users group" -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
        if(!(([ADSI]$perfoGroup).IsMember(([ADSI]"WinNT://BIZTALK2016/CrmAsyncServiceDEV").path)))
             {([ADSI]$perfoGroup).psbase.Invoke("Add",([ADSI]"WinNT://BIZTALK2016/CrmAsyncServiceDEV").path);}

        $output=Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock{
        function AddLogonAsAService($accountToAdd)
        {
          if( [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($accountToAdd) ) 
          {
            Write-Host "no account specified" -f red;
            exit;
          }
          $sidstr = $null
          try
          {
            $ntprincipal = new-object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount "$accountToAdd"
            $sid = $ntprincipal.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
            $sidstr = $sid.Value.ToString()
          }
          catch 
          {
            $sidstr = $null
          }
          Write-Host "Server:$env:computerName - Adding ""Logon as a Service"" right to Account: $accountToAdd" -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
          if( [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($sidstr) )
          {
             Write-Host "Account not found!" -ForegroundColor Red
             exit -1
          }
          #Write-Host "Account SID: $($sidstr)" -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
          $tmp = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
          #Write-Host "Export current Local Security Policy" -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
          secedit.exe /export /cfg "$($tmp)" 
                        
          $c = Get-Content -Path $tmp 
          $currentSetting = ""

          foreach($s in $c)
          {
            if( $s -like "SeServiceLogonRight*")
            {
              $x = $s.split("=",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
              $currentSetting = $x[1].Trim()
            }
          }
          if( $currentSetting -notlike "*$($sidstr)*" )
          {
            Write-Host "Modify Setting 'Logon as a Service'" -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
            if( [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($currentSetting) )
            {
              $currentSetting = "*$($sidstr)"
            }
            else
            {
              $currentSetting = "*$($sidstr),$($currentSetting)"
            }
            #Write-Host "$currentSetting"
            $outfile = @"
    [Unicode]
    Unicode=yes
    [Version]
    signature="`$CHICAGO`$"
    Revision=1
    [Privilege Rights]
    SeServiceLogonRight = $($currentSetting)
    "@
            $tmp2 = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
            #Write-Host "Import new settings to Local Security Policy" -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
            $outfile | Set-Content -Path $tmp2 -Encoding Unicode -Force
            Push-Location (Split-Path $tmp2)
      
            try
            {
              secedit.exe /configure /db "secedit.sdb" /cfg "$($tmp2)" /areas USER_RIGHTS 
            }
            finally
            { 
              Pop-Location
            }
          }
          else
          {
            Write-Host "NO ACTIONS REQUIRED! Account already in ""Logon as a Service""" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
          }
          Write-Host "Done." -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
        }
        AddLogonAsAService "BIZTALK2016\CrmAsyncServiceDEV";
        AddLogonAsAService "BIZTALK2016\CrmSandboxServiceDEV";
        AddLogonAsAService "BIZTALK2016\CrmAppServiceDEV";
        AddLogonAsAService "BIZTALK2016\CrmVssServiceDEV";
        AddLogonAsAService "BIZTALK2016\CrmMonServiceDEV";
      }
    }
    if(!(([ADSI]"WinNT://BTLab2016/Administrators,group").IsMember(([ADSI]"WinNT://BIZTALK2016/CrmAppServiceDEV").path)))
        {([ADSI]"WinNT://BTLab2016/Administrators,group").psbase.Invoke("Add",([ADSI]"WinNT://BIZTALK2016/CrmAppServiceDEV").path);}

    $output=Invoke-Command -ComputerName BTLab2016 -ScriptBlock{
      function createLogin()
      {
        try
        {
          $instanceName = "MSSQLSERVER"
          $LoginName = "BIZTALK2016\CrmAppServiceDEV"
          Import-Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking
          if ($instanceName -eq "MSSQLSERVER")
          {
            $server = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server -ArgumentList BTLab2016
          }
          else
          {
            $server = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server -ArgumentList BTLab2016\$instanceName        
          }              
          if ($server.Logins.Contains($LoginName))
          {    
            Write-Host $LoginName "Already exists..."
          }
          else
          {
            $SqlLogin = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Login -ArgumentList $server, "$LoginName"
            $SqlLogin.LoginType = 'WindowsUser'        
            $SqlLogin.Create()
            $SqlLogin.AddToRole('sysadmin')
            Write-Host $LoginName "Login created successfully"  -f darkgreen;
          }
        }
        catch
        {     
          Write-Host "Could not create Login - Error: " $($_.Exception.Message) -f red;
        }
       }
       createLogin;
      }
    }
Assign-Permissions;
```

Results:

[image: Assign Local Group Membership & Permissions for CRM Service Accounts]